# Filter or handle AuthenticationException in OAuth2

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to filter the AuthenticationException that is thrown during a user Authentication in my application. I know these cannot be filtered with **@ControllerAdvice** and **@ExceptionHandler**. So trying to figure out any Handler would work for my problem.

Already tried different approaches like **AuthenticationFailureHandler** but they didn't fit my requirement as I am using **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter**.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Spring security exceptions are handled by `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. You can create a custom filter that handles `AuthenticationException` and add it after `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. Default Spring security [Filter Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-ordering).

```
public class AuthenticationExceptionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (final Exception exception) {
            if (exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                this.logger.debug("Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point", exception);
            }

            if(exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                ....
            }

            // Check ExceptionTranslationFilter#handleSpringSecurityException(...)
        }
```

You can register the filter programmatically by overriding the configure method of [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html).

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new AuthenticationExceptionFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);
    }
```

---

For Centralized exception handling across all @RequestMapping:
Check out [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html)

> A convenient base class for @ControllerAdvice classes that wish to
>   provide centralized exception handling across all @RequestMapping
>   methods through @ExceptionHandler methods.
>
> This base class provides an @ExceptionHandler method for handling
>   internal Spring MVC exceptions.

Here's a sample code snippet to get you started:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
....
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomException(final CustomException exception, final WebRequest request) {

        return handleExceptionInternal(exception,
                                       ErrorOutputDto.create(exception.getErrorIdentifier(), exception.getMessage()),
                                       new HttpHeaders(),
                                       HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                                       request);
    }
....
```

Comment: Looks like this is similar to ControllerAdvice which does not suit my requirement as mentioned in the description. These handlers work only if the exception is raised within RequestMapping methods. But I need handlers for exceptions that are raised before invoking RequestMapping methods while authenticating the user as I am using OAuth2 for my application Security.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. But no luck yet. Are you sure this works for OAuth2 ? Beacuse you are suggesting for Spring security I guess that might not work for my case.

Comment: Spring Security provides support for OAuth 2.0. Debug the application to figure out if  request went throw your custom filter or not. You can also enable these debug flags for detailed logging `logging.level.org.springframework.boot.web.servlet=DEBUG`
`logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`
`logging.level.org.springframework.security.oauth2=DEBUG`
`logging.level.org.springframework.security.web=DEBUG`

Comment: I have been trying this for a while, it is good that I found this filter has been reached once Authentication is failed. But the exception is already handled by that time so it is not caught in any of the catch blocks with in doFilter method. Also, I tried to change the response with getOutputStream and it is throwing error like getOutputStream has already been called for this response.

Comment: Try adding your custom filter before `ExceptionTranslationFilter` see what happens. Use `HttpSecurity#addFilterBefore(..)`

Comment: I finally end up using a normal Filter instead of using GenericFilterBean. It worked for me. Thanks for all your inputs anyhow.